# How to display specific type of font inside a div with onclick using javascript?

Tags: javascript, fonts

I have a form with radio buttons each of which representing a different font. When the user selects one and hits create the font should appear in the display div.

Here is part of HTML and one of the buttons on the form:

```
<div id="form">
    <form id="nameForm" method="get" action="nowhere.php">
        <div class="formbox">
            <div id="radioTitle">
                Pick a font:
            </div>
            <label for="normal" class="normal">Normal</label>    
            <input type="radio" name="fonts" id="normal" />
    </form>
</div>

<div id="display">  
</div>
```

I'm not sure how to grab the font and get the specific one to display in the div using javascript.

```
function fonts(){
    if(wholeForm.normal.checked == true){

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/ug6Lu/3/

Note that you need any selected font to either be installed on the user's computer or loaded using css/javascript.

HTML:

```
<div id="form">
    <form id="nameForm" method="get" action="nowhere.php">
        <div class="formbox">
            <div id="radioTitle">
                Pick a font:
            </div>
            <label for="normal" class="normal">Normal</label>    
            <input type="radio" name="fonts" id="normal" />
    </form>
</div>

<div id="display">  
Example Text
 </div>
```

JS:

```
var checkRadio = document.getElementById('normal');
checkRadio.addEventListener("click", modifyFont, false);

function modifyFont(e){
    if(e.target.checked == true) {
        document.getElementById('display').style.fontFamily = "monospace";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this doesn`t seem to work tho. I can get it to display innerhtml but not display the font I want.

Comment: Actually I think I may have got it working thank you

Comment: Sorry, I was just showing the basic Javascript call. I've updated the answer with an example that actually works.

Comment: Thanks I got it working and am now trying to make so when I select an option for a color from a drop down list to display that font in that color.

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
.new-font {
  font-family: ...;
}
```

JS:

```
wholeForm.className = wholeForm.className + " otherclass";
```